# '0' syntax in string push_back

Tags: c++, syntax, character-encoding, char

i've just learned c++ fundamentally. I tried to convert int array to string and found this code online.

```
int arr[4] = { 1,2,3,4 };
std::string str;
for (int i : arr) {
    str.push_back(i + '0');
}
std::cout << str;
return 0;
```

Please someone explains for me what `'0'` mean??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'0' is character literal denoting the symbol '0'. According to the C++ Standard (2.3 Character sets):

> 3. ... In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each 
>      character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than 
>      the value of the previous.

So if you have character '0' then the expression '0' + 1 yields the value of the character '1'. the expression '0' + 2 yields the value of the character '2' and so on.

For example in the ASCII coding system character from '0' to '9' have sequential values from 48 to 57 inclusively. In the EBCDIC coding system characters from '0' to '9' have sequential values from 240 to 249 inclusively.

Answer (score 1):

It literally means the digit `0`, a character symbol that is used to represent the number or the digit zero. C++ uses the apostrophe to denote a single character literal.

Comment: Note that `'0'-'9'` range is contiguous, allowing to make sense to `'0' + i`. (which is not guarantied for `'a'-'z'`)

Answer (score 1):

It's a requirement of the language that any character set used to write C++ source has the digit characters 0 through 9 appear sequentially. So `i + '0'` converts the integer held in `i` into the character value that represents that number, as long as it's in the range 0 to 9. `1` becomes whatever value `'1'` is and so on.

Comment: C++ source code is written in the "basic **source** character set". The requirement about the digits applies there, but it is also a requirement on the "basic **execution** character set", and that's what matters here, since the value of `i` is determined at runtime.